# How can I disable Android and IOS app data backups in an Ionic/Capacitor project?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using the Ionic framework (using Capacitor) to create an app which will run on Android and IOS. I would like to disable automatic backup of the app's data on devices.

I figured out that I can set `android:allowBackup="false"` in the Application node in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I've not looked at IOS yet but presume there will be some similar setting in there.

I noticed that when the Android app is recreated from scratch using `npx cap add android`, the Android manifest is reset and `allowbackup` reverts to 'true'. Is there any way to disable the auto backups in my Ionic project, to save having to remember to do it manually in the Android Manifest? I looked in `capacitor.config.ts` in my Ionic project, but couldn't see an obvious way to do it.

Comment: why you need to recreate android platform every time? its just one time command. avoid using it each time. Just using `npx cap sync` to make changes available in natively.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib this will work yes. I was recreating as I was getting some issues with the Android project getting corrupted, so I was having to recreate it periodically. I've resolved those now, so ````npx cap sync```` is working fine now. It doesn't seem like there is any way to set the backups in Ionic, so I will just have to make those changes natively. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the correct answer is that there is no way to disable the auto backup directly in Ionic/Capacitor. So it needs to be done in the native code, e.g. for Android, set `android:allowBackup="false"` in the Application node in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

As long as you don't delete and recreate the Android project from scratch, you won't lose any native changes.